# perl error: Base class package "Class::DBI" is empty

Tags: perl, perl-module

I created new project using CGI programming with perl.

In `login.pl` I have a line of code :

```
use base 'Class::DBI';
```

and when i run login.pl using web browser apache error log file shows following error

```
Base class package `Class::DBI` is empty.

(Perhaps you need to 'use' the module which defines that package first,
or make that module available in @INC (@INC contains: ../shared  ../shared /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/perl/5.14.2 /usr/local/share/perl/5.14.2 /usr/lib/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/perl/5.14 /usr/share/perl/5.14 /usr/local/lib/site_perl)
```

Any help will be really appreciated.

Comment: Class::DBI hasn't had a release since 2007, everyone I know who used to use it has moved to [DBIx::Class](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBIx::Class).

Comment: [I am the original author of Class::DBI](https://metacpan.org/pod/release/MSCHWERN/Class-DBI-0.02/lib/Class/DBI.pm) and I **strongly** recommend you use DBIx::Class instead.  Class::DBI is obsolete and no longer maintained.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [perl manual on `base`](http://perldoc.perl.org/base.html#DIAGNOSTICS):

> - **Base class package "%s" is empty.**
>     base.pm was unable to require the base package, because it was not found in your path.

It sounds like you either don't have `Class::DBI` available or you have your paths configured incorrectly.

Comment: I tried to install it using cpan and it says

cpan[1]> install DBI
Going to read '/root/.cpan/Metadata'
  Database was generated on Tue, 17 Mar 2015 22:53:37 GMT
DBI is up to date (1.633).

Comment: DBI is a different package than Class::DBI

cpan> install Class::DBI

Answer (score 0):

This solved the issue

cpan> install Class::DBI

cpan> install Class::DBI::AbstractSearch